# What's the duration of Savage Transformation?

Tags: dnd-4e, wizard, powers

What's the duration of the wizard level 5 attack power, [Savage Transformation](http://www.wizards.com/dnd/Article.aspx?x=dnd/4ex/20111024)?

The card reads:

> Hit: 2d8 + Intelligence modifier damage, and you partially transform
>   the target's mind and body into that of a savage monster (save ends).
>   Until this transformation ends, the target must make an opportunity
>   attack against any creature that willingly leaves a square adjacent to
>   it, and if any creature ends its turn adjacent to the target, the
>   target must use a free action to deal damage to that creature equal to
>   5 +your Intelligence modifier.

…but there's no mention of the duration!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10):

The power lasts **until the target makes a successful saving throw**, as per the quoted text, or the character dies.

Comment: It should be noted that no 4th Edition powers (at least, to my knowledge) have a specific duration beyond "until the start of your next turn." Everything that doesn't last for a single turn uses "save ends" instead, or allows you end the effect whenever you chose (such as stances).